# Logback - do not create empty log files at startup

Tags: startup, logback, logfile

I have a project with a lot of 'tool' classes that have their own logging. Those logfiles are created at startup of the application, but remain empty, until used.

**Is it possible to tell logback that empty files should not be created at startup? But only when they are being used?**

Somehow I don't find information on this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official support for lazy/on-demand creation of log files in Logback's `FileAppender`.

However there are some known configuration workarounds that may achieve the same result. For more details see the [Logback feature request 202 "FileAppender should permit lazy file creation"](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-202).

My personal favorite is the variant using the LazyFileOutputStream and a custom implementation of a FileAppender. A working implementation of an [LazyFileOutputStream can be found in Alessio Pollero's log4j-additions section](https://github.com/aleroot/log4j-additions/blob/master/src/org/pollerosoftware/file/LazyFileOutputStream.java).

An the LazyFileappender code is very simple:

```
public class LazyFileAppender<E> extends FileAppender<E> {

    @Override
    public void openFile(String file_name) throws IOException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            File file = new File(file_name);
            boolean result = FileUtil.createMissingParentDirectories(file);
            if (!result) {
                addError("Failed to create parent directories for [" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
            }

            LazyFileOutputStream lazyFos = new LazyFileOutputStream(file, append);
            setOutputStream(lazyFos);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```